# Решение задачи связности методом быстрого поиска ( Седжвик )

Tags: c++, алгоритм, visual-studio, visual-c++

В книге Роберта Седжвика "Алгоритмы на C++" в самом начале есть решение задачи методом быстрого поиска ( программа 1.1 :). Несколько раз перечитал, так и не понял как она функционирует. Решил просто забить ее и посмотреть как работает. При запуске какие бы числа не вводил, она ждет еще ввода. Решил попробовать пошагово запустить в отладчике Visual Studio 2015 - каждый раз она крашится. Ошибок в коде не выдает, просто вылетает как обычная программа Windows. В чём может быть проблема? Задача известная, но только пару вопросов на ней нашел и никаких ответов, что вводить и как функционирует. Из за чего крашится вообще непонятно.

Вот код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
static const int N = 10000;
int main()
{
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

int i, p, q, id[N];
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    id[N] = i;
}
while (cin >> p >> q) {
    int t = id[p];
    if (t == id[q]) continue;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (id[i] == t)
        {
            id[i] = id[q];
        }
    }
    cout << " " << p << " " << q << endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Видимо нужно будет найти оригинал книги на английском языке и посмотреть. В приведенном коде есть явные ошибки. К примеру

```
int i, p, q, id[N];
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    id[N] = i;
}
```

внутри цикла пишем за пределы массива. Похоже, это инициализация и скорее всего хотели написать такое

```
int i, p, q, id[N];
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    id[i] = i;
}
```

этот код должен как минимум работать.

Что же весь код будет делать - я  смутно представляю. Могу только сказать, что оно в цикле просит пару чисел и если выполняется условие - модифицирует массив и выводит эти же числа. Где здесь быстрый поиск - я не знаю.

Comment: Спасибо. Проверю на ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Про `id[N] = i;` уже заметил @KoVadim.

А дальше хитрость заключается здесь:

```
while (cin >> p >> q) {
}
```

Оно выйдет из цикла только по достижению EOF. Если я правильно помню, в виндовой консоли EOF можно симулировать нажатием `Ctrl-Z`.

---

**Update: Что делает программа**

`p` и `q` - это 2 объекта (в данном случае - числа), которые нужно проверить на связанность друг с другом. Связанность в данном случае - это не какое-то свойство чисел/объектов, это вот, грубо говоря, Вы захотели их связать - и связали.

Для проверки создается массив, для которого `p` и `q` - обязательно валидные индексы в массиве. В случае данной программы массив заполняется уникальными значениями, то есть, на начальном этапе никакие объекты не связаны друг с другом. Объекты будет связывать пользователь, вводя данные.

После получения двух объектов, которые нужно связать, программа находит элемент по индексу `p` и сохраняет его значение во временной переменной. Далее она сравнивает его с элементом по индексу `q`. Если они равны, то ничего делать не нужно - они уже `связаны`. Иначе она проходит по всем элементам массива и в элементы, значение которых равно сохраненному значению, записывает значение элемента по индексу `q`. Теперь `p` и `q` стали `связаны`.

То есть, программа выполнила `объединение`, `связывание`. Еще раз повторюсь, это абстрактная связь, какие-то свойства объектов не изменились, как было 2 числа, так и осталось. Собственно, на этом программа завершается.

Где же здесь поиск? Для проверки, являются ли объекты `p` и `q` связанными значениями теперь достаточно будет проверить равенство элементов по индексам `p` и `q`. Если равны - значит, связаны. Это операция `поиска`, собственно, почему он и назван быстрым. Ну и теперь нетрудно заметить, что сам поиск в программе все же есть: `if (t == id[q])`.

Comment: А как это влияет на креши?

Comment: @KoVadim Никак.В вопросе есть фраза `При запуске какие бы числа не вводил, она ждет еще ввода.` Теперь автор вопроса знает, каким образом программа завершается. А крешится скорее всего именно по причине, замеченной Вами. У меня в книге, кстати, все окей, `id[i] = i;`.

Comment: а, да,  это он под отладчиком запустил. Но там логично оно работает - потому как для дебага студия обычно создает массивы немножко больше (на пару элементов), что бы отслеживать подобные выходы за пределы массива. А закрешится оно по выходу. Но до выхода ТС не добрался.

Comment: @Vladimir Спасибо. А то в книге совсем не понятно как они вдруг так связались. Ну и про Ctrl-z не догадался, до этого программы всегда писал с явной возможностью выхода, не подумал, что нужно до конца добивать массив или прерывать. Ошибки проверю, либо у меня такой перевод, либо где-то опечатался.

Comment: @Vladimir,@KoVadim Спасибо всем за помощь. Да вылетало как раз из-за запись за пределы массива. Смутило, что в дебаге не вылетало ( не знал о таком поведении студии). Ошибку в массиве сам допустил, пока переносил из книжки, стыдно теперь что целый вопрос создал:( Но зато понял про "абстрактную связь", объяснили лучше, чем в книге - спасибо огромное.